# Changing the first ViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

Initially I developed the app with only one ViewController(called MainView). Now I'd like to add one ViewController (called LoginView)infront of MainView. I added in the AppDelegate as

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    LoginPage *RootViewController = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginPage"];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController = RootViewController;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

It looks working, but only black screen appears.
My LoginPage ViewController has the following structure. The ViewController has two buttons, one label and one text view. They don't appear and only black screen is appearer.

[image]

Comment: your code works fine for me.

Comment: what is your initial view controller ?

Comment: Set  loginviewcontroller as initial view controller in storyboard.

Comment: Should works, maybe your RootViewController is nil, check it.

Comment: @KathiravanG, how to set it? Thanks

Comment: @WilliamHu, where to check RootViewController is nil. Thanks

Comment: @Mr.T, that is my problem. I don't know how to set initial view controller.

Comment: Just ```NSLog``` it, by the way the first letter of variable should not uppercase.

Comment: As mentioned in the below answer, go to your storyboard and select your view controller and make it as initial view controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just mark your Login view controller as initial view controller in storyboard

[image]

Comment: Thanks igor. That is the solution.